# How to enable output-hashing in angular 17 (prerender mode)

Tags: angular

I have a project that upgraded to **Angular 17**. Now I want to build the project in `prerender mode`. To do this, I'm using the following command (the project name is '**suproject**'):

```
ng run suproject:prerender
```

The problem is, how can I enable --output-hashing? I've tried the following two methods and neither worked:

method 1:

```
ng run suproject:prerender --output-hashing=all
```

method 2:(in angular.json)

```
architect => build => options => "outputHashing": "all",
or
architect => build => configurations => production => "outputHashing": "all",
```

my angualr.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "suproject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "rj",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/suproject/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/xxxx.txt",
              "src/assets",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/nginx.conf",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf",
              "pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer",
              "lodash.clonedeep",
              "flat"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/toastr.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/styles/ng-select.scss",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-multiple.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/styles.scss",
                "inject": true
              }
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/styles"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [],
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "300kb",
                  "maximumError": "600kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "suproject:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "suproject:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "suproject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets/images/logo/favicon/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/suproject/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "externalDependencies": [
              "canvas"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/assets/styles"
              ]
            },
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "suproject:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "suproject:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "suproject:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "suproject:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routesFile": "./src/pre-render-routes.txt",
            "discoverRoutes": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "suproject:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "suproject:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "suproject:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "suproject:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "suproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "transloco:optimize": "transloco-optimize dist/suproject/browser/assets/i18n",
    "postbuild": "gulp COMPRESS_JS_FILE",
    "start:dev": "ng serve --port=4200",
    "start": "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 4200 -c-1 dist/suproject/browser",
    "build:dev": "ng build --configuration=production && npm run transloco:optimize",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration=development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "docker:build": "docker build -t suproject .",
    "docker:run": "docker run --rm -it -p 4200:80 suproject",
    "build": "ng run suproject:prerender && npm run transloco:optimize"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.1.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^12.0.7",
    "@ngneat/transloco": "^6.0.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.1",
    "ckeditor4-angular": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.7.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^13.2.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^16.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^11.1.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^16.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "persian-utilities": "^1.1.1",
    "pretty-print-json": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "ssr-window": "^4.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.1.2",
    "@ngneat/transloco-optimize": "5.0.3",
    "@types/ckeditor": "^4.9.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.16",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  }
}
```